Queries consuming high Sharable Memory in AWR
I have faced some performance issue at the database and while investigating I'v noticed the below dynamic sampling queries. Note that the dynamic sampling parameter is 2, and the table statistics is up to date.
Taking on consideration the queries doesn't include a dynamic sampling hint and I have searched in the AWR for such hint which I couldn't find.
My questions is ,why I am facing this queries? is the high value of sharable memory count affect the SGA memory and what is the impact of it ?
Example of the queries
SELECT /* OPT_DYN_SAMP */ /*+ ALL_ROWS IGNORE_WHERE_CLAUSE RESULT_CACHE(SNAPSHOT=3600) opt_param('parallel_execution_enabled', 'false') NO_PARALLEL(SAMPLESUB) NO_PARALLEL_INDEX(SAMPLESUB) NO_SQL_TUNE */ NVL(SUM(C1), 0),
 NVL(SUM(C2), 0), NVL(SUM(C3), 0), COUNT(DISTINCT C4), 
NVL(SUM(CASE WHEN C4 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0),
 COUNT(DISTINCT C5), NVL(SUM(CASE WHEN C5 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) 
 FROM (SELECT /*+ IGNORE_WHERE_CLAUSE NO_PARALLEL("table") FULL("table") NO_PARALLEL_INDEX("table") */



Level 2 is a special level (and the default) for dynamic sampling. It basically allows Oracle to auto-determine the actual DS level. So 2 = auto. If you want to disable dynamic sampling, you'd have to set it to 0 or 1 (which would only use it if stats were missing). You can also investigate why DS is engaging - clearly Oracle thinks your stats are insufficient for the queries being asked of it. You might need histograms on certain columns; you might need some extended stats on column groups, etc...
However, don't assume that just because there are all these DS queries in the shared pool that they are consuming too many resources. You should normally only investigate cursor memory consumption issues if you are actually running out of shared pool memory or throwing shared pool memory allocation errors. Otherwise, just treat it as normal and move on to other things.
That being said, 4096 versions is indeed an awful lot and may indicate a problem that can cause shared pool issues down the road. If you want to investigate cursor reuse issues (the reason why a new version or child cursor gets created instead of an existing one reused) you'll need to look at v$sql_shared_cursor for one of the sql_ids of interest. There a lot of possible reasons for non-reuse, but that's the place to identify what the situation is in your case.

thanks for you answer, for the first point the stats and histogram are there , I am considering to alter table move as it will eliminate any fragmentation or high water mark issue then ill update the stats with its histograms.
for the 2nd point if you can provide a link or more details bcz i didnt find info about it in google, the 3rd point those sql is are for the dynamic sampling so i am not sure how to tune them. though ill have a look it.
